# Split a folder which has 100s of subfolders with each having few files into one more level of subfolder using shell

Tags: bash, shell, directory, file-structure

I have a following data dir:

```
root/A/1
root/A/2
root/B/1
root/B/2
root/B/3
root/C/1
root/C/2
```

And I want to convert it into following file structure:

```
root2/I/A/1
root2/I/A/2
root2/I/B/1
root2/I/B/2
root2/I/B/3
root2/II/C/1
root2/II/C/2
```

Purpose of doing it is I want to run some script which takes home folder (root here) and runs on it. And I want to run it in parallel on many folders(I, II) to speed up the process.

Simple assumption about file and folder name is that all are alphanumeric, even no period or underscore.

Edit: I tried following:

```
for i in `seq 1 30`; do mkdir -p "root2/folder$i"; find root -type f | head -n 4000 | xargs -i cp "{}" "root2/folder$i"; done
```

Problem is that it creates something like following, which is not what i wanted.

```
root2/I/1
root2/I/2
root2/I/1
root2/I/2
root2/I/3
root2/II/1
root2/II/2
```

Comment: And do you know which directories go into `A` and which into `B`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. did u mean which directories go into I and which into II. I don't care much about it. I just want them to be equally divided, say in 30 groups. So that i can invoke my command on 30 folders.

Comment: If I understood the question, you can do something along these lines: `a=0; for i in $(ls); do let a++; [[ $(($a % 60)) -gt 30 ]] && mv $i I || mv $i II; done`

Comment: @Uno, can u please explain what you are trying to do here. I have edited my question for more clarity.

Comment: @Shweta Didn't have much time so I quickly wrote it to dispatch top level folders into 2 groups, taking them 30 by 30, but the question wasn't 100% clear so I just added a comment.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you do not want to copy the individual files, but whole directories. In that case, you should use something like `find -type d -name "[A-Z]"`, or whatever matches the directory level you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to use a lesser known command called `dirsplit`, the usual application of which is to split a directory into multiple directories for burning purposes.

Use it like below :

```
dirsplit -m -s 300M /root/ -p /backup/folder1

Options implies below stuff :
-m|--move     Move files to target dirs
-e 2 special exploration mode, 2 means files in directory are put together
-p prefix to be attached to each directory created, in you case I, II etc
-s Maximum size allowed for each new folder created.
```

---

For more information see :

```
dirsplit -H
```

---